# How can I override corefile (controller file) in Magento?

Tags: magento

I have to add a custom function in the controller file. Instead of changing the core file, I have place this file in local folder (following the same directory structure) and added my custom code. But still the old controller file is being used by Magento. How can I call this new controller file?

Comment: Do you have added a config.xml for the modul and set your new modul to active?

Comment: yes i have added the config.xml but i dont know how to active new module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, controller overriding doesn't work by copy pasting the controller file in app/code/local folder with the same hierarchy of folders unlike Block/Helper/Model overriding.

In order to override a controller, follow the following xml block:

```
<config>
    <frontend> [1]
        <routers>
            <checkout> [2]
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <yourModule before="Mage_Checkout">Namespace_Module_Overwrite_Checkout</yourModule> [3]
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

```
Where,
[1] Depending on the controllers area "frontend“ or "admin“
[2] Router node of the module to be overridden (look it up in the config.xml of that module)
[3] The tag  can be anything, it must be unique within the  node.
Your_Module_Overwrite_Checkout (is mapped to directory)
Your/Module/controllers/Overwrite/Checkout/

Hope this helps.
Happy E-Commerce!!
```